# Sum of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sqrt{n+2}-2\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Find the sum of
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty(\sqrt{n+2}-2\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}).
$$
I tried to find if the series is positive(I think it's not), and then to find the sum. I tried some of the test for convergent and I didn't get anything.

I tried to simplify the sum (I put numbers for n) and then I get :
1- sqrt(2) + sqrt(n+2)-sqrt(n+1) and now I don't know how to continue

Comment: Show us what you tried. What values of $n$ are you summing over?

Comment: are you asking for $\sum_n \sqrt{n+2}-2\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}$?

Comment: @Arnaldo yes I ask for that

Comment: @AaronHendrickson I tried to put numbers, (n = 1, 2, .. ) and I saw that many numbers are delete, in the end I have just :
1 - sqrt(2) - sqrt(n+1) + sqrt(n+2),
I tried to find the limit of the 2 last : sqrt(n+1) + sqrt(n+2)

Comment: Simplify this: $$(\sqrt3-2\sqrt2+\sqrt1)+(\sqrt4-2\sqrt3+\sqrt2)+(\sqrt5-2\sqrt4+\sqrt3)+(\sqrt6-2\sqrt5+\sqrt4)+(\sqrt7-2\sqrt6+\sqrt5)+(\sqrt8-2\sqrt7+\sqrt6).$$

Comment: @YvesDaoust I tried this like I wrote before, I get in the end:
1 - sqrt(2) - sqrt(n+1) + sqrt(n+2)

Comment: @shir You should edit your question to include anything you've tried. The lack of this context is why you are receiving downvotes.

Comment: Take the limit of the simplified form.

Answer (score 4):

The sum converges , is negative and equals $1-\sqrt{2}$
Note that the summand consists of telescoping sums.
Rewrite
$$\sqrt{n+2}-2\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}=(\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n+1})-(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}) $$
Summing it up gives the result $1-\sqrt{2}$